# JavaFX: Animation during Window/Stage change

Tags: animation, javafx, scenebuilder

How to create an animation during the changing of stages?

-For instance, I have 2 stages that have different sizes(Width and Height). Normally, without any animations, the 2nd screen just pops out in an instant. I want the 2nd stage to show smoothly(like opening or closing a window in Mac OS Sierra). All tutorials that I can find are mostly about animations in changing scenes. Maybe my way of searching is wrong.

Here's how I change stages.

```
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(Insert FXML here));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
```

Any thread that are related to what I'm looking for is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an AnimationTimer. 
Timeline won't work becuase the Properties of the Stage are read Only.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(Insert FXML here));
Parent root = loader.load();
Stage stage = new Stage();

stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.show();


//set your Stage width,height,x,y to zero

stage.setX(0);
stage.setY(0);
stage.setWidth(0);
stage.setHeight(0);
AnimationTimer t = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                stage.setX(stage.getX()+1);
                stage.setX(stage.getX()+1);
                stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth()+1);
                stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight()+1);
                // Here put your condition for "destination and desired size" 
                 // in this case everything will move/grow by 600 px
                if( stage.getX() == 600){
                    this.stop();
                    stage.setResizable(false);
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

This won't look smooth enough, but you can figure out an "interpolation" mechanism, to make a even smooth movement.

**EDIT**:

I forgot! You also can use Transitions:

```
Animation transition = new Transition() {
    {
        setCycleDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_IN);
    }
    @Override
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        // frac is the percentage of how much time of the Transition
        // Already passed (1000 ms => frac = 0.5)
        // Here you just Multiply frac with the designated value
        stage.setHeight(height*frac);
        stage.setWidth(width*frac);
        stage.setX(x*frac);
        stage.setY(y*frac);        
    }
};
transition.play();
```

This tends to be smoother since you can use the Interpolator

Comment: @VayneMain_345 i edited my Answer because, I forgot that you can also use **Transitions** for smooth interpolation.

Comment: Note you can still use `Timeline`. The x, y, width, and height properties of window may all be read-only but they still have setters which you can wrap in a `WritableValue`.

Comment: @Luxusproblem The second one worked better. But how do you make the animation start in the center? Both started in the upper left.

Comment: @VayneMain_345 instead of  setting the values of the Stage to zero, you could use the center. But in that case you need to look how to apply the interpolation from the center, instead from the "origin". When you want to have the Stage always on center, then set the window to the center of you screen. And when you interpolate you need to calculate x and y: like : `stage.setX(centerX-width*frac/2)` and `stage.setY(centerX-height*frac/2)` . But The Renderer of Java FX will have issues with "resizing of the stage". It will not be as Smooth, like if you would transition a node.